# How to list values in a tree that satisfy certain predicates?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tree

The tree is nonbinary as it can have more than 2 children. Each node has a list of children. Here I am writing `list_if` which returns a list of values from tree that satisfy the predicate `p`. As i test my code, It shows `'int' object is not iterable`. Does someone know how I can write the code?

```
def list_if(t, p):
    """
    Return a list of values in Tree t that satisfy predicate p(value).

    Assume p is defined on all of t's values.

    @param Tree t: tree to list values that satisfy predicate p
    @param (object)->bool p: predicate to check values with
    @rtype: list[object]

    >>> def p(v): return v > 4
    >>> t = descendants_from_list(Tree(0), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3)
    >>> list_ = list_if(t, p)
    >>> list_.sort()
    >>> list_
    [5, 6, 7, 8]
    >>> def p(v): return v % 2 == 0
    >>> list_ = list_if(t, p)
    >>> list_.sort()
    >>> list_
    [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
    """  ###gather_lists() eliminates lists in list
    return gather_lists([t.value if p(t.value) else []] +[list_if(x, p) for x in t.children])
```

Comment: **Where** does it show that?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the traceback (the long error message).  Just above the line that says something like:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

is should show the line of your program where the error happened. (That's why it helps to post the traceback in your question.)

In this case, the program was trying to iterate over an `int`.  And the interpreter is telling you that can't be done.

I suspect the line with the error has something like `for x in y:`, and y is an `int` instead of a list  (if the error is in the `list_if` function, look at t.children.  It is probably not being set properly when the tree is built)